# C++: Boost: Need help with directory navigation logic

Tags: c++, boost, boost-filesystem

So, I'm trying to change my directory to save files, and then change back to the directory I was previously in.

Essentially:

```
cd folder_name
<save file>
cd ../
```

Here is the code I have so far:

```
void save_to_folder(struct fann * network, const char * save_name)
{
    boost::filesystem::path config_folder(Config::CONFIG_FOLDER_NAME);
    boost::filesystem::path parent_folder("../");


    if( !(boost::filesystem::equivalent(config_folder, boost::filesystem::current_path())))
        {
            if( !(boost::filesystem::exists(config_folder)))
            {
                std::cout << "Network Config Directory not found...\n";
                std::cout << "Creating folder called " << Config::CONFIG_FOLDER_NAME << "\n";
                boost::filesystem::create_directory(config_folder);
            }
            boost::filesystem::current_path(config_folder);
        }

    fann_save(network, save_name);
    boost::filesystem::current_path(parent_folder);

}
```

Currently, what is happening is this every time the method is called:
Folder doesn't exist: gets created
Folder doesn't exist: gets created

It's not doing the `cd ../` part. =(

so my directory structure looks like this:

folder_name
- folder_name
-- folder_name
--- folder_name

Comment: I think you can remove the last line of code `boost::filesystem::current_path(parent_folder);`. Whenever you enter the function you set the path to the folder you want to work on.

Comment: I wouldn't have used "../" for the parent folder, but just "..".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to the docs, the current_path method is a little dangerous because it might be modified by other programs at the same time.

So it would probably be better to operate from the CONFIG_FOLDER_NAME.

Can you pass a larger path name to fann_save? something like:

```
if( !(boost::filesystem::exists(config_folder)))
{
    std::cout << "Network Config Directory not found...\n";
    std::cout << "Creating folder called " << Config::CONFIG_FOLDER_NAME << "\n";
    boost::filesystem::create_directory(config_folder);
}
fann_save(network, (boost::format("%s/%s") % config_folder % save_name).str().c_str());
```

otherwise if you are happy with using current_path or cant use a larger path in fann_save, i would try something like:

```
boost::filesystem::path up_folder((boost::format("%s/..") % Config::CONFIG_FOLDER_NAME).str());
boost::filesystem::current_path(up_folder);
```

Answer (score 0):

Can you try with this code instead.

```
void save_to_folder(struct fann * network, const char * save_name)
{
    boost::filesystem::path configPath(boost::filesystem::current_path() / Config::CONFIG_FOLDER_NAME);

   if( !(boost::filesystem::exists(configPath)))
   {
       std::cout << "Network Config Directory not found...\n";
       std::cout << "Creating folder called " << Config::CONFIG_FOLDER_NAME << "\n";
       boost::filesystem::create_directory(configPath);
   }
   fann_save(network, save_name);
}
```